# How do I apply coalesce to rows to eliminate the nulls?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce

I am trying to transform this:

| Email | ADName | ADDName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| davis@company.com | NULL | Dave Davis |
| davis@company.com | Dave Davis | NULL |
| davis@company.com | NULL | NULL |
| davis@company.com | NULL | NULL |

Into this:

| Email | ADName | ADDName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| davis@company.com | Dave Davis | Dave Davis |

So I thought the SQL COALESCE (Microsoft SQL Server 2012) would do the trick, but I am not sure it's the tool for the job. I get the impression it's not intended to operate across rows.

Thought I'd try a simple start on one col:

```
SELECT COALESCE (       
        SELECT 
          ADName
        FROM 
            MyTable
)
```

But that doesn't even pass the syntax check. What is the correct way of doing it?

EDIT:
OK, so doing a Group By, Max solves the immediate problem on a column where there are only two possible values in the group.

What about if it is more complex, with more columns and more values to evaluate? As in

| Email | ADName | ADDName | OtherName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| davis@company.com | NULL | Dave Davis | NULL |
| davis@company.com | Dave Davis | NULL | NULL |
| davis@company.com | NULL | NULL | Dave Davis (User) |
| davis@company.com | NULL | NULL | Dave Davis (Admin) |

I am seeking this final result:

| Email | ADName | ADDName | OtherName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| davis@company.com | Dave Davis | Dave Davis | Dave Davis (User) |
| davis@company.com | Dave Davis | Dave Davis | Dave Davis (Admin) |

I have the suspicion this is becoming a python problem or similar.

Comment: `Group by` + `max`?

Comment: Yep, ok. But let me extend that a bit further.....I'll edit the question

Comment: You really don't need the old data for your question - you only need the data which demonstrates the most complex situation, not the most simple.

Comment: SQL Server 2012? You might want to start thinking about moving to a newer version

Comment: What would you expect to get if there were 2 non-null values in multiple columns.  Would you expect all combinations to come out?  eg.  if ADName has "A" and "B" and Columsn ADDNAME has "X" and "Y" and OtherName has "M","N'",  you would then want to get:
davis@company, A,X,M
A,Y,M
A,X,N
A,Y,N
etc?

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you'll make it much easier for us to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that to get all combinations you would want to do something like this:

```
select E.email, X.ADName, Y.ADDName, Z.otherName
from (select T.email from T group by T.email) as E
left join (select T.email, T.ADName from T where T.ADName is not null) X on X.email = E.email
left join (Select T.email, T.ADDName where T.ADDNAME is not null) Y on Y.email = E.email
left join (select T.email, T.otherName from T where T.otherName is not null) Z on Z.email = E.email
```

Comment: This is intuitively correct for me. My real world code has seven additional columns, and I'd  be wondering about performance. I've got about 20,000 rows and 11 cols total, 10 of which need this logic applied to it. I shall have to experiment....    BUT, it does cater for all scenarios, I think.

Comment: 19,441 rows in under 10 secs - perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Just an option use `max() over()` and distinct

```
with cte as ( 
Select EMail
      ,AdName  = max(ADName) over (partition by email)
      ,AddName = max(ADDName) over (partition by email)
      ,OtherName
 from YourTable
)
Select Distinct *
 From  cte
 Where OtherName is not null
```

**Results**

[image]

Comment: One wonders whether it might actually be possible that any of the name columns could be null - would need OP to clarify.

Comment: Yes, any of the name columns could be null. And btw John, there's a typo in your 4th line AddName

Comment: @Maxcot Typo fixed - bad copy paste.     This would trap all null columns except email

Comment: You've said `Where OtherName is not null` but it might be null.

Comment: Yes, this is a niggle. There is no one column other than email which I have absolute faith in. Any column can have anything including nulls, and the best I can hope for (I think) is reduce rows, not necessarily have a perfect result. There will be a (User) and and an (Admin) version of the same email address.

Comment: @DaleK Do you mean EVERY record NULL ?   If so, we could test a count of distinct values.

Comment: I think, if I understand correctly, that there is the potential for any column other than email to not exist at all for a given email, but any might exist, or might exist with multiple different values...